# Nothing happens on Wordpress Update command

Tags: plugin-development, mysql, wpdb

I made a function in Wordpress, which should update one field **status** to **0**. But no changes are made to the database. I don't know what is the reason. Can someone please help.
I tried looking into wordpress own **wp-db.php**, and seen that the same array is going there as well.

```
        function updateData($temp_array){
            global $wpdb;
            $temp_array = array('status', '0');
            echo $wpdb->update( 'wp_testing_options', $temp_array, array( 'id' => 1 ) );
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this:

```
$temp_array = array('status', '0');
```

should be

```
$temp_array = array('status' => '0');
```